# Load SQL infile with first column fixed width

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a plain text file with data like this:

```
B01-CA  This is first data
Z01     This is second data 
A56-COL This is third data
```

So I want to insert these data in a table with 3 columns id, code, name.

I know the syntax:

```
load data local infile 'C:/codes.txt'
into table tbl_test
fields 
terminated by ' '
enclosed by ' '
lines 
terminated by '\n'
(code,name);
```

But how can I take first substring upto 8 charactrs in **code** column and rest line till '\n' to **name** column. **id** is auto increment. Any ideas will help.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same question.
I have done this:

```
load data local infile '<file>' into table <table_name> (@row) set code = trim(substr(@row, 0,7)), name = trim(substr(@row, 8))
```

it works for me